# How to query for the 'other' double quotes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I converted a large amount of data from mssql to mysql and a few of them came in with the 'other' double quotes ... the sharper ones.

I would like to do a query in phpmyadmin for all the entries that have that symbol because its breaking my query (coming back as null) but cannot figure out how to write it ...

SELECT * FROM table where id LIKE '%&#32%' <-- i dont actually know what the ascii symbol is for that one and this html ascii convention doesnt work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find one of them, can't you just copy it and paste it into your LIKE clause? That will prevent you from having to figure out the ASCII code for it.

Comment: That might have been the answer, sheesh so obvious... I cant tell now though because it turns out that out of thousands of them I only had about 3 like this and I manually fixed them based on the ID.